# SqlTruncateException: Numeric arithmetic causes truncation

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclient

We have a stored procedure which saves balances to db.
Today we got the exception:

> SqlTruncateException: Numeric arithmetic causes truncation.

We received a balance exceeding 1 billion, and that caused this exception. I don't care whether such huge value is erroneous or not, but I'd like to know the reason for strange behavior of SqlCient.

We pass a collection of balances:

```
public class LoroAccountBalance
{
    ...     
    public decimal? Balance { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

which is mapped to user defined table type:

```
create type Settlement.LoroBalanceType as table
(
    ...
    Balance                     money               not null,
    ...
)
```

So .net `decimal` type is mapped to sql `money`.

Here is the last step of the stack trace:

> System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal n, int precision, int scale)

SqlClient decides to adjust decimal precision before converting it to money type.
However it chooses such a value for `precision` for which 1b won't fit.

I'd like to understand why he does so. I could not find explanation in [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx).

Comment: How do you pass that `decimal` value to the server?

Comment: @Luan we convert collection of balances to IDataReader and pass it as type Structured

Comment: it'd be nice to know if you identified the problem here ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's precision and not the scale?  Do you know the exact decimal which is failing?  Is it possible it has more than 4 digits after the decimal?  SQL Server MONEY only has 4 digits after the decimal, while decimal does not have that limit.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx

Comment: Yes, original value has only two digits.

Comment: I will have to test.  There should be no limit around 1bn in any case.